# Перенос значений из xml в xml с разными структурами

Tags: php, xml

Есть 1 xml: https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0ISK6N
И есть второй: https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0ISK6Q

Нужно из второго файла в первый как то передать:
1. `coordinates` из `Placemark` второго файла в `Placemark` первого файла
2. `simpledata` хотя бы в виде одной строки из `Placemark` второго файла в `description` первого файла

Comment: Появилась нужда это сделать, но с php не работал никогда. поэтому прошу помощи

Comment: Код за вас всё равно никто не напишет. В PHP для работы с XML есть SimpleXML https://www.php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php. Другой вопрос зачем вам PHP если вы с ним не работали, используйте инструмент с которым работали.